# Blogger data:i.url <a name> target

Tags: blogger

I'm styling a blogger template that has a large header area that hides posts below viewable screen level. I need the archive links to push the page up and display the posts at the top of the screen. Normally I'd use http://mysite.com/mypage.htm**#top** pointing to **a name="top"** which is placed underneath the header.

But blogger uses **'data:i.url'** and I don't know how or where to add **#top** to that?

Please know that I'm no programmer, so keep it basic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add an `#top`

```
<a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#top&quot;'>LINK</a>
```